# How to make a function that takes code like "SELECT * FROM SOME_TABLE" as an input and returns a table as an output?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I want to create a function that takes some code as an input (e.g. `Select * FROM SOME_TABLE`) and returns the result of a query as an output.

I want to use it in procedures in order to return tables as a result.

It should look like this:

```
BEGIN
    --some procedure code
    CREATE TABLE SOME_TABLE as Select * FROM ...;
    Select * FROM table(my_function('Select * FROM SOME_TABLE'));
END;
```

Important tips:

1. The resulting table can have **multiple columns**, from 1 to +inft
2. The resulting table can have **multiple rows**, from 1 to +inft
3. So the size of a table can be both very small or very large.
4. The input query can have several `where`, `having`, `partition`, and other Oracle constructions.
5. I want to have a table as an output, not `DBMS_OUTPUT`.
6. I can't install any modules/applications, or use other languages hints. However, I can manually create types, functions, procedures.

I tried to search in the net but could not find a solution that meets all my expectations. The best link I've found was this:

https://sqljana.wordpress.com/2017/01/22/oracle-return-select-statement-results-like-sql-server-sps-using-pipelined-functions/

Comment: https://github.com/method5/method4

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, unfortunately, due to my company's restrictions I can't install `PL/SQL` modules/applications. Corrected the question description.

Comment: If you can't create PL/SQL package or functions, then you can't run dynamic SQL to begin with.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I can create but I can't install external packages.

Comment: @Alex I'm the maintainer of that repository.  Let me know if there's anything I can do to help with the rules against external packages.  For example, if your company is worried about cost, it's open source.  Feel free to send me an email if I can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT` works if your "code" is a select query

```
DECLARE
l_cur SYS_REFCURSOR;
l_query VARCHAR2(4000) := 'select * from SOME_TABLE';
BEGIN
    OPEN l_cur for l_query;
    DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(l_cur);
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a function that has a string as parameter and return a cursor.
select statement you should pass as a string. in a function you can open a Cursor.

```
declare
  v_sql varchar2(100) := 'select 1,2,3,4,5 from dual';
  cur_ref  SYS_REFCURSOR;

  function get_data(in_sql in varchar2) return SYS_REFCURSOR 
  as
    cur_ret  SYS_REFCURSOR;
  begin
    OPEN cur_ret FOR in_sql;

    return cur_ret;
  end;
begin

  :cur_ref := get_data(v_sql);

end ;
```

if your select statement is longer than 32K than you maybe should use a clob instead of varchar2 for your Parameter type. But you have to try that